# How might I write a "defn" macro in Clojure?

Tags: macros, clojure

I was practicing writing macros and I can't seem to get `defn` to work.

My syntax is: `(my-define name parameter body)`

Ignoring & parameters and recursive routines, How do I bind the name to a (fn[parameter] body)?

Comment: You can use `macroexpand` to see in the repl what a macro expands to. E.g. `(macroexpand '(defn foo [] 1))`. This is useful both in debugging your own macros, as well as trying to learn from the clojure/core macros.

Comment: May also use `(source defn)` to directly inspect the source code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to transform

```
(my-define <name> <args> <body>)
```

to

```
(def <name> (fn <args> <body>))
```

This is quite simple actually:

```
(defmacro my-define [name args body]
  `(def ~name (fn ~args ~body)))
```

Comment: This doesn't facilitate functions with multiple forms in the body, nor docstrings.

Comment: For multiple forms use the splice operator (@) -> ~@body